# DataGridView updates itself for the first time only after I resize a column or row

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I tried to find a solution so please check your questions first!
I tried `BindingSource` between `DataGridView` and `DataTable` but no use.
I tried to bind the `DataGridView` to the `DataSource` after every loop. The problem is that the contents of `DataGridView` does not update even if the data is there. It's only dark grey. If I resize the columns/rows with my mouse after some data has been added to my `DataTable`, the `DataGridView` gets updated nicely and all the rows will appear!.

Here is some of my code:

```
Public Class DatagridviewComponent
dim sataSet as New DataTable
Public Sub New()
 InitializeComponent()
 me.dataSet.Columns.Add("Name", GetType(String))
 DataGridViewProcesses.DataSource = dataSet
End Sub
```

So, a simple `DataGridView` binded to a `DataTable`.
Now, what I do after that...

```
Public Sub UpdateData(ByVal str As String)
 For i as integer = 0 to dataSet.Rows.Count -1
  If dataSet.Rows(i)(0).ToString = str Then
   dataSet.Rows(i)(0) = str
   Exit Sub
  End If
 Next
dataSet.Rows.Add(str)
End Sub
```

So, I check if I already have a line called `str` and I overwrite. If `str` is a new item, I add it to `dataSet`. This was an example, not my actual code but I think this should demonstrate the problem I have.
There are many questions about this topic but I didn't find any working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get a little better results when I did a `Me.Refresh()` after I add a `DataRow` to the `DataTable`.

Like this:

```
Public Sub UpdateData(ByVal str As String)
 For i as integer = 0 to dataSet.Rows.Count -1
  If dataSet.Rows(i)(0).ToString = str Then
   dataSet.Rows(i)(0) = str
   parent.RefreshForm()
   Exit Sub
  End If
 Next
dataSet.Rows.Add(str)
parent.RefreshForm()
End Sub
```

Where parent is Form1. In Form1 I now have this:

```
  Public Delegate Sub RefreshFormDelegate()
  Public Sub RefreshForm()
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
      Me.Invoke(New RefreshFormDelegate(AddressOf RefreshForm))
      Return
    End If
    Me.Refresh()
  End Sub
```

Now the `DataGridView` updates nicely after every line I add/modify in the `DataTable`. I don't need to use a `BindingSource`. It's the same, with or without a `BindingSource`.

But now one problem still remains: My `DataGridView` is FROZEN, there is no scrollbars (like there should) and I can't select a row unless I first either resize or sort COLUMNS... Well difficult to explain but it still is a problem!

Answer (score 0):

There are so many syntax errors in your example code that I can only assume this was written here, not in VB and then copied.  But ignoring them, your issue is related to the fact that the datatable, which is your datasource for your grid, does not implement [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) which means it does not tell the grid that you added a new row.  You need to use something like an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) or BindingSource, as you said you had tried.

Knowing you had tried it, I can only assume you did not use it right.  Set the datasource of your grid to the bindingsource, then when you add a new row in your datatable, you must ALSO add it to your BindingSource.

Hope this helps you down the right road.

Comment: I tried to 1)Dim bsource As New BindingSource 2)DataGridViewProcesses.DataSource = bSource 3)dim dataRow as DataRow 4)populate dataRow! (checked, works) 5)dataSet.Rows.Add(dataRow) and bSource.Add(dataRow). Works still the same way. Datagridview updates itself after I resize a column or row. When I get new data after resizing, DataGridView updates itself like I want.

Comment: I use this same method (mentioned on original post) when I bind DataTable to a ChartControl and it updates itself everytime with no hassle.

Comment: What you did with the BindingSource looks right. Edit your original post and ADD an example of the code using the binding source (include methed and event handlers so we get a full picture). Sometimes it's the little things that you cant see without the whole picture.